# Why intuitively is the tangent vector the derivative of velocity of position with respect to their modulus?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, vectors, differentiation, calculus

When trying to find the tangential velocity, many textbooks define the tangent direction as one of the following:

[image]

or

[image]

Intuitively, why is the tangent vector the derivative of the position with respect to its modulus? Or the velocity with respect to its modulus? Why necessarily in the tangential direction?

Comment: What is dr and ds representing?

Comment: @TheSpaceGuy dr is the infinitesimal variation of the position vector and ds the infinitesimal variation of the position vector's modulus

Comment: Well, then dr/ds is representing unit vector along the tangent(direction of the motion).

Answer (score 1):

Symbol $s$ is not the modulus of $\mathbf r$, it's the distance travelled. You can see that as $\Delta s\to0$, then $|\Delta\mathbf r|\to \Delta s$ as well. Intuitelvely, it's because the arc of a sufficiently smooth curve can be better and better approximated with the line as you move ends together.

Since, $|\Delta\mathbf r|\to \Delta s$, then $|d\mathbf r/ds|=1$, in other words $\mathbf t = d\mathbf r/ds$ is a unit vector tangential to the curve

[image]

Comment: This makes sense. However can't there be motion where |\Delta\mathbf r|\ remains conctant while distance travelled changes? Wouldn't this make  |\Delta\mathbf r| \ =0 while the distance continues to change?

Comment: Also could you further explain how the line segment on the graph relate to your answer?